# Python returns a different excel file name while parsing

Tags: python-3.x, xlrd

I have a folder where the name of the folder is **158851** and it has a single excel file named **158851-2.XLSX**, but while I read it through the code below it shows a weird name like below appending a ~$ before the actual file name.

```
 import xlrd
 df = xlrd.open_workbook("C://Users//xyz//Documents//Auto_Excel//abc//temp//158851//158851-2.XLSX",on_demand=True)
```

> C://Users//cheta//Documents//Auto_Excel//Nag//temp//158851//~$158851-2.XLSX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into similar situation, here is what you may need to check.

Get into **158851** folder and check properties there. Check if you have a **hidden file** or a empty file, also check why your code is **unable to handle** that particular file.

Answer (score 1):

File names starting with `~$` are usually used to denote temporary files. In your case you load the file with the `on_demand` flag which as [the documentation](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/on_demand.html) says:

> ... allows saving memory and time by loading only those sheets that the caller is interested in, and releasing sheets when no longer required.

This means that it works in a temporary file and shows you that, loading and releasing things as it sees fit. It does not present you the original file directly but rather shows you its memory-optimized view.

Try leaving the `on_demand` flag out to use the original file.

Comment: I already tried removing on_demand also tried by making on_demand=False but nothing worked.